# Cannnot access public folder in laravel8

Tags: css, laravel, directory, display, public

In laravel app, I have kept my css and js is asset folder inside public folder  and I call these css my blade using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css') !!}">
```

but when Execute page in browser , this css file is not executing so I tried to access this url directly through browser url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css'
then the result shows like 'This page is not working'.

my pblic folder css accessing tree is
public/assets/front-end/assets/css
Please advise

Comment: Welcome to SO.. can you put your error screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

change it:

```
href="{!! asset('assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css') !!}"
```

to:

```
href="{{ asset('assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}"
```

{!! !!} is for rendering tags in text

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you check your public folder, css file location.

Change it -
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css') !!}">`

Right - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}">`

or

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/') }}assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">`

I hope this is help for you!

Answer (score 0):

to access a resource in Laravel you need to use the `{{  }}` syntax and call the `URL::asset()` method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('/assets/front-end/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}">
```

more details about accessing resources in laravel: [how to access file in public folder](https://www.edureka.co/community/65971/how-to-access-images-inside-public-folder-in-laravel)